# Cannot resolve symbol mapValue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

### I am getting this error, where am I going wrong. Please help as I am new to spark. How will I use mapValues on an RDD

package com.udemyexamples

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object AverageFriendByAge {

  def parseFile(line:String): Unit =
  {
    val field= line.split(",")
    val age=field(2).toInt
    val friend=field(3).toInt
    (age,friend)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark=SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("AverageFriendAge")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sc=spark.sparkContext
             .textFile("C:\\SparkScala\\SparkScalaStudy\\fakefriend.csv")

     val rdd=sc.map(parseFile)
    val y= rdd.**mapValues**(x => (x, 1))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you first need an instance of `SparkSession`, your code should look like :

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("dataFrameExample")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```